# LocalStorage in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I've started writing a greasemonkey script, and am facing problems performing localstorage in the Greasemonkey script. The only way I could figure out localstorage in GM is by creating another instance of Javascript in the `newElement.innerHTML` DOM property, but there the rest of my variables are inaccessible.

Any ideas ? Here's the Greasemonkey code fragment I'm working on.

```
        var testHref = anchorTag[i].href;
    var testHTML = anchorTag[i].innerHTML;
    var patHref = /item\?id=[0-9]*/g;
    var patCaptureId = /item\?id=([0-9]*)/g;
    var testId = patCaptureId.exec(testHref);
    var patHTML = /[0-9]* comment(|s)/g;
    var patHTML2 = /discuss/g;
    if(patHref.test(testHref) && !patHTML.test(testHTML) && !patHTML2.test(testHTML))
    {
        newElement = document.createElement('span');
        newElement.style.color = "#FF0000";
        newElement.innerHTML = "<a href=\"javascript:localStorage.setItem( 'one', 'rishabhVerma' ); var test = localStorage.getItem( 'one' ); console.log( test );\"> B</a>";
        anchorTag[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, anchorTag[i].nextSibling); 
    }
    i++;
```

Answer (score 13):

If you just need to store values you can go the classic Greasemonkey way using `GM_getValue()` and `GM_setValue()` functions which work pretty well.

- http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue
- http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue

Comment: @Basilevs on the other hand, very large amounts of data _will_ cause localStorage to spit out exceptions at you ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak my comment about data amounts is no longer relevant -  Greasemonkey [uses SQLite to store values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20976405/125562).

Answer (score 8):

hmm, unsafeWindow.localStorage doesn't work I guess? I know it's not a problem for chrome to get the localStorage, never tried it on firefox to be honest.

Comment: I just used `unsafeWindow.localStorage` in a Greasemonkey script (in Firefox 3.6 on Mac) and that seems to work fine.

Comment: Please note, that using unsafeWindow will allow webpages detect and potentially minipulate greasemonkey, if it is able to trap the events that occur when the unsafeWindow object is called.

This information can be verified [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/greasemonkey-hacks/0596101651/ch01s13.html)