# Get value setted in GM_setValue from a custom Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Do you know if a custom Firefox extension can read values setted calling GM_setValue() from a GraseMonkey user script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values exists in about:config, (enter "greasemonkey" in the filter).

Perhaps there exists an easier way to get them, though...

Comment: Can't find those in Firefox 27.0

Comment: These require to install the Greasemonkey addon.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm pretty sure addon is installed. Do you think I wrote my own userscript driver? Anyway, I've found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Greasemonkey 1.13](http://www.greasespot.net/2013/12/greasemonkey-113-release.html) `GM_setValue()` [uses an SQLite db](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1798) to persist values.
This DB can be accessed directly (see https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/master/modules/miscapis.js).